# maximum number of non attacking pairs of queens in 8 queens

Tags: math, optimization, combinatorics, n-queens

Maximum number of non-attacking pairs of queens in 8-Queens problem is given by 8 × 7/2 = 28. Can someone explain how it is 8x7/2?

Comment: Every queen can have 7 non-attacking queens. 8 queens will have overall 8x7=56 non-attacking queens. Because pair contains of two queens - result 8x7 will be divided by 2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non attacking pair is when two queens don't attack each other.For max condition no queen attacks any other queen, so number of non attacking pairs

1st queen would have = 7 
2nd queen would have = 6 
(exclude the pair with the 1st queen as its already counted in step 1)

Similarly, 3rd queen would have = 5

Thus, total number of non attacking pairs for 8 queens would be = 7+6+5+4+3+2+1+0 =28

Answer (score 1):

Here is another thought process:
We have 8 queens and you want to know every possible attacking pair on the board so we have 8 choose 2
or

```
8!/((8-2)!*2!) = 28
```